# Is there a way to update a database table with a python dictionary?

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I am trying to write data back into the column of a database table.

The data is stored in a python dictionary, because I need the key to identify the row I want to update.

Here a snippet of my code so far:

```py
l = []
for line in text:
    soup = bs(line, 'html.parser')

    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract() 

    autor = soup.get_text()

    s = autor.replace('\n', '')
    l.append(s)

dictW = dict(zip(t,l))
```

```py
sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET Reintext WHERE = ...'
cursor.executemany(sql, dictW)
```

dictW looks like this :

```py
{'file:/C:/Users/125.html' : 'long string of a html file'}
```

I am stuck at the UPDATE statement.

How can I write it to update the database table with the values in the dictionary while using the keys as identifier?

Comment: Show an instance of what `dictW` looks like.

Comment: Hey @Tomalak I included it in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for key in dictW:
    x = dictW[key]
    print(key, x)
```

This look gives you key and value separately so you can use them in your SQL statement. This will iterate through your dictionary so you can get a list of keys and values separately for your SQL statement

```py
sql = 'UPDATE tablename SET Reintext WHERE ? = ? '
cursor.executemany(sql, (key, x))
```

Comment: Hi @OneCrazyGenius, thanks for your help. When I am tyring your solution I am getting the error: (156, b"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: Maybe you need ==

Comment: Sugar, just realised the SQL is wrong, you need to update the columns and the value so you get `"UPDATE tablename SET column = value WHERE row = number"` See [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)